# Devart dotConnect for Oracle in Visual Studio 2015 - compatibility problems

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, devart, dotconnect

Visual Studio 2015 is now supported as well for dotConnect. The setup file SetupODTforVS2015.exe was released in Oct 2015 (download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html)). I'm using oracle version 8.4 and Visual Studio 2015 and would like to get Oracle Developer Tools. The installation didn't show any errors, but afterwards no change visible - still not working. Has someone experience with ODT for VS 2015 or does anyone know if oracle 8.4 is incompatible? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=33364) in the devart forum:

> With Visual Studio 2015 you need to use dotConnect for Oracle 8.4.422
>   or higher or to compile license resources manually.

I was using minor Version 8.4.225.0.

Seems as if there's no way around compiling licences manually or upgrading dotConnect.